# Ignoring empty arguments for certain flags

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I have a command that takes 1 argument and can take several flags.

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('item')
@click.option('--list-items', help='list items', is_flag=True)
def cli(item, list_items):
    if list_items:
        click.echo(ITEMS)
        return
```

currently it returns:

```
Error: Missing argument "item".
```

How can I make so that I could access the functionality of --list-items even if I don't provide an argument? Just like --help flag does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to make `item` optional:

```
@click.argument('item', required=False)
```

then do error handling in the function (e.g. raise a [`BadParameter()` exeception](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#click.BadParameter)).

Comment: Can't believe I missed it, been going through docs for 30 minutes and couldn't find it :D
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You made it mandatory argument, make it optional by either adding required= False or by adding a default value to it